# Adding the "isExportable" attribute to an excel xmlMaps.xml file

Tags: python, excel, xml, dynamics-nav

So for a previous question I asked how to add a custom made xmlMap to an excel file in python and I was "successful" by opening the xlsx file as an archive and extracting the file structure, followed by adding the xmlMaps.xml file to the structure and including it in the "rels". I can now open the excel file and see that the xml source map is attached, but I cannot export it. It mentions that I need to set the attribute "xmlmap.isExportable" to True, but I have no clue about how to do this, preferably using python.
All I have found on google is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xmlmap.isexportable

My old question regarding the case: [Adding XML Source to xlsx file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70667250/adding-xml-source-to-xlsx-file-in-python/70687607#70687607)

Any help is greatly appreciated

Best regards
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to understand how a xlsx file works and how xml connections are stored and referenced throughout multiple sub files